# Maximum number of apples that can be collected

Tags: arrays, algorithm

A monk initially at his house moves sequentially from one farm to other.There are a total of N farms.

**House->1st farm->2nd farm-> ... ->Nth farm**

Running from one farm to the next one consumes a single unit of Monk's current energy.
Initially Monk is at his house, and to move to the first farm it shall take him one unit of energy.

You are given the arrays **milk[N]** and **apples[N]** and the monk's initial energy **P**(at house).

At each farm, Monk has one choice either to take milk ( for increasing his energy by amount of **milk[i]**) or apples from the farm. Monk is allowed to take only either the entire amount of Milk or the entire amount of apples and not none or both.

By following so, what is the maximum number of apples Monk can collect, always having non-negative energy ?

Example:

```
N = 3   
P = 2  
milk = {1, 2, 1}  
apples = {100, 1, 100}

ans = 200
```

Any approach or algorithm to solve the above question..

Comment: Sounds like a case for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
dp[i, j] = maximum amount of apples possible if we are at farm i
           with j energy
```

We have the recurrence:

```
dp[i, j] = max{dp[i-1, j+1] + apples[i] # Take the apples at i, only if j >= 0
               dp[i - 1, j - energy[i]] # Take the energy at i
```

Then take the max of `dp[N - 1, _]` (if using zero indexing).

For your example, `dp` will be:

```
dp[0, P-1] = dp[0, 1] = apples[0] = 100
dp[0, P-1+milk[0]] = dp[0, 2] = 0
dp[0, anything else] = -inf

dp[1, 0] = max{dp[0, 0 + 1] + apples[1],
               dp[0, 0 - 2]}
         = 101
dp[1, 1] = max{dp[0, 1 + 1] + apples[1],
               dp[0, 1 - 2]} 
         = max{0 + 1, -inf}
         = 1
dp[1, 2] = max{dp[0, 2 + 1] + apples[1],
               dp[0, 2 - 2]}
         = -inf
dp[1, 3] = max{dp[0, 3 + 1] + apples[1],
               dp[0, 3 - 2]}
         = 100

dp[2, 0] = max{dp[1, 0 + 1] + apples[2],
               dp[1, 0 - 2]}
         = 101
dp[2, 1] = max{dp[1, 1 + 1] + apples[2],
               dp[1, 1 - 2]}
         = -inf
dp[2, 2] = max{dp[1, 2 + 1] + apples[2],
               dp[1, 2 - 2]}
         = max{200, 101}
         = 200
```

You need to iterate the `j` on the `i`th iteration up until the sum of `milk[0] + milk[1] + ... + milk[i]`.

Various optimizations might be possible in the implementation, such as only using one or two arrays instead of a matrix.